# How to count rows with specific value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this `SELECT`, it shows result of match, but it count Goals even if Goal = 0. How can I define to count only where goals is equal to 1?

```
SELECT 
    B1.Name AS HomeTeam, ISNULL(C1.Goal, 0) AS HomeTeamScore, 
    ISNULL(C2.Goal, 0) AS AwayTeamScore, B2.Name AS AwayTeam
FROM 
    Match A
INNER JOIN 
    Team AS B1 ON A.HomeTeamId = B1.TeamId
INNER JOIN 
    Team AS B2 ON A.AwayTeamId = B2.TeamId
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT MatchId, TeamId, COUNT(Goal) AS Goal
     FROM PlayerMatch
     INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerId = PlayerMatch.PlayerId
     GROUP BY MatchId, TeamId) C1 ON A.MatchId = C1.MatchId AND A.HomeTeamId = C1.TeamId
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT MatchId, TeamId, COUNT(Goal) AS Goal
     FROM PlayerMatch 
     INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerId = PlayerMatch.PlayerId
     GROUP BY MatchId, TeamId) C2 ON A.MatchId = C2.MatchId AND A.AwayTeamId = C2.TeamId
```

Comment: What is the data type of goal? Is it an int or bit?  Can it only have the values 1 and 0?  Or does it sometimes contain 3, 4, etc?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a `WHERE` condition saying `where goal <> 0` or use conditional `count()` like

```
COUNT(case when Goal <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS Goal
```

Make your subquery like

```
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT MatchId, TeamId, COUNT(Goal) AS Goal
            FROM PlayerMatch
            INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerId = PlayerMatch.PlayerId
            WHERE Goal <> 0 ---Here
            GROUP BY MatchId, TeamId) C1
```

Comment: 0 also take as a count 1

Comment: may be it will work COUNT(case when Goal <> 0 then 1 end) AS Goal

Answer (score 2):

Use this.

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MatchId, TeamId, COUNT(Goal) AS Goal
        FROM PlayerMatch
        INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerId = PlayerMatch.PlayerId
        GROUP BY MatchId, TeamId) C1 ON A.MatchId = C1.MatchId AND A.HomeTeamId =C1.TeamId 
        Having COUNT(Goal) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

simple if you have value 0 or 1 in Goal

```
sum(Goal) AS Goal
```

OR

```
 COUNT(case when Goal <> 0 then 1 end) AS Goal
```

Comment: I think the OP intends `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that COUNT() counts all non-null values, not just values > 0.

As a result, use:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN goal > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

or shortened to:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN GOAL > 0 THEN 1 END)
```